# .net Maui WhiteLabeling: How to have different Styles.xaml- and Colors.xaml-Files and use BuildConfiguration in .csproj to use the right one

Tags: msbuild, maui, csproj

I create a whitelabeling app in maui and need aplly different Ressources for different Customers befor the App compiles. For App-Icon, Fonts, Images it is not complicated. I created diffrent Build Configs and Item Groups that have Conditions with the right ressource path for the customer. The only think, that is not spezified in the .csproj, is the Styles Files-Location. I tried diffrent approaches to set a custom location, but I dont have found the right solution. The last thing I tried, is a prebuildscript that copy the Style-Files in the Ressources/Styles directory. But this don't work properly. Can somone help me with a solution? Would be very grateful for that.

**My .csproj:**

```
......
......
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;Debug-Green;Debug-Blue</Configurations>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug-Green|AnyCPU'">
  <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);GREEN</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug-Blue|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);BLUE</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**My first Solution (For MauiIcon, MauiImage... it works great, for Colors & Styles it dosen't work):**

```
<ItemGroup Label="Green" Condition="'$(DefineConstants.Contains(`GREEN`))'">
.....
.....
    <MauiXaml Include="Resources\_Green\Styles\Colors.xaml" LogicalName="Resources\Styles\Colors.xaml" />
    <MauiXaml Include="Resources\_Green\Styles\Styles.xaml" LogicalName="Resources\Styles\Styles.xaml"/>
</ItemGroup>


<ItemGroup Label="Blue" Condition="'$(DefineConstants.Contains(`BLUE`))'">
.....
.....
    <MauiXaml Include="Resources\_Blue\Styles\Colors.xaml" LogicalName="Resources\Styles\Colors.xaml" />
    <MauiXaml Include="Resources\_Blue\Styles\Styles.xaml" LogicalName="Resources\Styles\Styles.xaml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**My actual Solution (it works, but not consistently):**

```
<Target Name="PreBuildBlue" Condition="'$(DefineConstants.Contains(`BLUE`))'" AfterTargets="PreBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="xcopy Resources\_Blue\Styles\ Resources\Styles\ /y" />
</Target>

<Target Name="PreBuildGreen" Condition="'$(DefineConstants.Contains(`GREEN`))'" AfterTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="xcopy Resources\_Green\Styles\ Resources\Styles\ /y" />
</Target>
```

Also I have a big problem to add a postbuild script, to clear the Styles-Folder. Because when I add the script, the build fails. The build don't find the Color.xaml and Styles.xaml, although the files exist in the folder during the build.

**My postbuild-script:**

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="rmdir /s /q Resources\Styles\ " />
</Target>
```

Comment: Post build? Shouldn't this be pre build, or I am not getting it right?

Comment: For my second solution my intention was to copy the Style-Files in the right folder and after build clean the folder. I have PreBuildScript with condtions for the copy and an global PostBuild script for the cleaning afterwards.

Comment: Shouldn't the files remain in the folder? I mean, If you want to debug something? I may be mistaken.

Comment: We use TFS and the possibility for false Style chek-in is huge. The cleaning is a safty mechanism. I tried to clean befor build, but the build produces the same error: the files not found. I search for the best solution to do that. And this is to specify the location of the files and don't use pre- and PostBuildScripts, because the scripts not always work.

Comment: @AlbertRuff Do you mean you are using Team Foundation Server to build the MAUI app?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT At the moment, we don't use TFS for build. We use TFS for Source Control

Comment: Is there any error log when running the postbuild script during the build process?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Yes, there is an error: `3>CSC : error CS1566: Error reading resource '******.Maui.Resources.Styles.Colors.xaml' -- 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Ent\***\Trunk\App\*****.Maui\***.Maui\Resources\Resources\Styles\Colors.xaml'.'
3>CSC : error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Ent\***\Trunk\App\*****.Maui\***.Maui\Resources\Styles\Colors.xaml' could not be found.
3>CSC : error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Ent\***\Trunk\App\*****.Maui\***.Maui\Resources\Styles\Styles.xaml' could not be found.`

Comment: The error indicates that the compiler had trouble with the file name passed to the Resources, see:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1566?view=netstandard-1.5

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT But I don't change the names. This error only apears, when I use the PostBuild script to clean the Styles-folder. I wonder, is there a way to specify or ovveride the standard path to the Styles Folder. Or is the path Hardcoded for Maui

Comment: @AlbertRuff Thanks for the update, currently I don't think we can override the standard path to the Styles Folder.